# Generate lazy "spiral" in Scala

Tags: scala, yield, spiral

Task:
For a given position in 2D array generate list of surrounding positions located in radius.

For example:

```
input: (1, 1)
radius: 1
output: ( (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), 
          (0, 1),         (2, 1),
          (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2) ).
```

I wrote something like

```
def getPositions(x:Int, y:Int, r:Int) = {
  for(radius <- 1 to r) yield {
    List(
      for (dx <- -radius to radius) yield Pair(x + dx, y - radius),
      for (dx <- -radius to radius) yield Pair(x + dx, y + radius),
      for (dy <- -radius to radius) yield Pair(x + radius, y + dy),
      for (dy <- -radius to radius) yield Pair(x - radius, y + dy)
    )
  }
}
```

In this code getPositions returns not a sequance of points, but a sequance of Tuple4 of sequances of points. 
How can I "concatenate" 4 generators listed in code? Or is there more concise solution for my task? (I'm pretty new to scala).

P.S.
It's actually for my starcraft bot.

Comment: You repeat all your corner points.  I doubt you want to do that.  Change your second two for loops to go from `-(radius-1)` to `(radius -1)`.

Comment: Did anyone here help? Please choose an correct answer if so. Also, how's the bot coming along?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to flatten the List (twice), so this would do:

```
def getPositions(x:Int, y:Int, r:Int) = {
  for(radius <- 1 to r) yield {
    List(
      for (dx <- -radius to radius) yield Pair(x + dx, y - radius),
      for (dx <- -radius to radius) yield Pair(x + dx, y + radius),
      for (dy <- -radius to radius) yield Pair(x + radius, y + dy),
      for (dy <- -radius to radius) yield Pair(x - radius, y + dy)
    ).flatten
  }
}.flatten
```

It’s not a ‘lazy’ spiral, though.

**Edit**

That one is lazy:

```
def P(i:Int, j:Int) = { print("eval"); Pair(i,j) }

def lazyPositions(x:Int, y:Int, r:Int) = {
  (1 to r).toStream.flatMap{ radius =>

    (-radius to radius).toStream.map(dx => P(x + dx, y - radius)) #:::
    (-radius to radius).toStream.map(dx => P(x + dx, y + radius)) #:::
    (-radius to radius).toStream.map(dy => P(x + radius, y + dy)) #:::
    (-radius to radius).toStream.map(dy => P(x - radius, y + dy))
  }
}


print(lazyPositions(1,1,1).take(3).toList) # prints exactly three times ‘eval’.
```

I’ve used the `def P` method to show the real laziness. Everytime, you’d create a `Pair`, it gets called. In a lazy solution, you’d only want this on demand.

Comment: Will resulting list still be "lazy" (like generators in python)?

Comment: No, don’t be confused by the `yield` keyword. It is not a generator.

Comment: The logic is not correct to get the desired spiral, I don't think.

Comment: Yes, there are several problems with logic (order, duplicate corners and so on), but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
object Spiral
{
    def
    getPositions(x: Int, y: Int, r: Int): Seq[(Int, Int)] = {
      for { radius <- 1 to r
            dx <- -radius to radius
            dy <- -radius to radius
            if dx != 0 || dy != 0
      } yield
          (x + dx, y + dy)
    }


    def
    main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        printf("getPositions(1, 1, 1): %s%n", getPositions(0, 0, 1).mkString("{ ", ", ", " }"))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
getPositions(1, 1, 1): { (-1,-1), (-1,0), (-1,1), (0,-1), (0,1), (1,-1), (1,0), (1,1) }
```

Comment: Ups, a mistake.
This will output whole area of points in radius, except center point. That's not what I want. I need only bounds

Comment: That isn't going to work as written, since you'll generate a square each time with the central point missing.  You either need to drop the `radius <- 1 to r` and just use `r`, or you need to separate out the inner pieces.  (You could write a conditional that only passed if you were on a perimeter, but that's be `O(n^2)` for an `O(n)` problem.

Comment: @xap4o: Check out what Rex says. I replicated your radius-1 spiral, but didn't try larger radii.

Answer (score 1):

You can form your ranges directly, and use `flatMap` and `++` to join the lists together as they're made, and you might like to go in a circular direction also:

```
def getPositions(x: Int, y: Int, r: Int) = {
  (1 to r) flatMap (radius => {
    val dx = -radius to radius
    val dy = -(radius-1) to (radius-1)
    dx.map(i => (x+i, y+radius)) ++ dy.map(i => (x+radius, y-i)) ++
    dx.map(i => (x-i, y-radius)) ++ dy.map(i => (x-radius, y+i))
  })
}
```

If you really want the result to be lazy, you'll have to do the same with lazy components:

```
def getPositions(x: Int, y: Int, r: Int) = {
  Stream.range(1,r+1) flatMap (radius => {
    val dx = Stream.range(-radius,radius+1)
    val dy = Stream.range(-(radius+1),radius)
    dx.map(i => (x+i, y+radius)) ++ dy.map(i => (x+radius, y-i)) ++
    dx.map(i => (x-i, y-radius)) ++ dy.map(i => (x-radius, y+i))
  })
}
```

Edit: fixed a dx vs. dy typo.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few solutions to this problem. First, if you do not care for the order, just the positions, this will do:

```
def getPositions(x:Int, y:Int, r:Int) = for {
  yr <- y - r to y + r
  xr <- x - r to x + r
  if xr != x || yr != y
} yield (xr, yr)
```

That will give the exact same output you specified. However, you want a Python-style generator, so this would be more appropriate:

```
def getPositions(x:Int, y:Int, r:Int) = Iterator.range(y - r, y + r + 1) flatMap {
  yr => Iterator.range(x - r, x + r + 1) map { 
    xr => (xr, yr)
  }
} filter (_ != (x, y))
```

That will return an `Iterator`, which you can iterate through using `next`. Check for the end using `hasNext`.

You may replace `Iterator` with `List` or `Stream` or stuff like that and get a fully generated collection.

Now, let's assume you want a spiral starting at the center and moving one position at a time. We could do it with something like this:

```
def getPositions(x:Int, y:Int, r:Int) = new Iterator[(Int, Int)] {
  private var currentX = x
  private var currentY = y
  private var currentR = 1
  private var incX = 0
  private var incY = 1
  def next = {
    currentX += incX
    currentY += incY
    val UpperLeft = (x - currentR, y + currentR)
    val UpperRight = (x + currentR, y + currentR)
    val LowerLeft = (x - currentR, y - currentR)
    val LowerRight = (x + currentR, y - currentR)
    val PrevSpiral = (x, y + currentR)
    val NextSpiral = (x - 1, y + currentR)
    (currentX, currentY) match {
      case NextSpiral => incX = 1; incY = 1; currentR += 1
      case PrevSpiral => incX = 1; incY = 0
      case UpperLeft => incX = 1; incY = 0
      case UpperRight => incX = 0; incY = -1
      case LowerRight => incX = -1; incY = 0
      case LowerLeft => incX = 0; incY = 1
      case _ =>
    }
    if (currentR > r)
      throw new NoSuchElementException("next on empty iterator")
    (currentX, currentY)
  }
  def hasNext = currentR <= r
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stream that walks around the edges.

Assuming input (3,3),2 gives

```
{(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (4,1), (5,1),
 (1,2),                      (5,2),
 (1,3),                      (5,3),
 (1,4),                      (5,4),
 (1,5), (2,5), (3,5), (4,5), (5,5)}
```

then you could use the following:

```
def border(p: (Int,Int), r: Int) = {
  val X1 = p._1 - r
  val X2 = p._1 + r
  val Y1 = p._2 - r
  val Y2 = p._2 + r
  def stream(currentPoint: (Int,Int)): Stream[(Int,Int)] = {
    val nextPoint = currentPoint match {
      case (X1, Y1) => (X1+1, Y1)
      case (X2, Y2) => (X2-1, Y2)
      case (X1, Y2) => (X1, Y2-1)
      case (X2, Y1) => (X2, Y1+1)
      case (x, Y1) => (x+1, Y1)
      case (x, Y2) => (x-1, Y2)
      case (X1, y) => (X1, y-1)
      case (X2, y) => (X2, y+1)
    }
    Stream.cons(nextPoint, if (nextPoint == (X1,Y1)) Stream.empty else stream(nextPoint))
  }
  stream((X1,Y1))
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> val b = border((3,3),2)
b: Stream[(Int, Int)] = Stream((2,1), ?)

scala> b.toList
res24: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,1), (3,1), (4,1), (5,1), (5,2), (5,3), (5,4), (5,5), (4,5), (3,5), (2,5), (1,5), (1,4), (1,3), (1,2), (1,1))
```